# Replace text pdf pdfbox using newLineOf

Tags: java, pdfbox

How can i replace / overwrite current text using pdfbox. I have the following code . If i use PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.OVERWRITE Then it says im trying to overwrite and should use append instead. Thus printing my page as blank.

```
WARN o.a.p.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream - You are overwriting an existing content, you should use the append mode
```

If i use PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND , nothing happens and page displays as original

```
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(byteArr); // bytearr from file 

    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, doc.getPage(0), PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.OVERWRITE, false)) {

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER, 12);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(xLoc, yLoc); // Position of text i want to replace
        contentStream.showText("N/A"); // new text
        contentStream.endText();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

all streams are closed accordingly. Followed https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_adding_text.html

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: You can use overwrite. The warning just warns you that your existing content is lost. If you want to append (i.e. keep existing stuff), don't forget to set the fifth parameter to true. If it still doesn't work, please tell the values of xLoc, yLoc.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr xLoc, yLoc are just float values . basicly x and y position

Comment: I know what it is meant for. I'd like to know the actual values. And the size of the page. Btw `*fifth* parameter to true` is not a typo. You have only 4 parameters, this is a frequent mistake when appending to an existing page.

Comment: Still no change to it when i add the fifth parameter to true

Comment: You may also want to save the PDF, and maybe share it. And I'm still waiting for the x and y positions.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr here are the values 674.20996  449.41837 . Found the problem why it was not printing , issue with my list not populating.  With the new values its printing but on top of the page any sugestions why this might be?

Comment: Y axis starts at the bottom in PDF, not at the top like in java. And you can get weird effects if you're not setting the fifth parameter to true. (you didn't tell if you did) And the numbers are not pixels, these are 1/72 of an inch.

Comment: Thanks . I am setting the fifth value to true .

Comment: Another possibility is that your page is very small. 449 is close to the middle, but only for an A4 page. Call `page.getCropBox()` to see the size.

Comment: Yet another possibility is that the lower left is not the origin of the coordinates. The same applies: *Call `page.getCropBox()` to see the position.*